# django rest framework: routers.DefaultRouter() url with custom path

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to define a path to access a certain api. What works so far (urls.py):

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'test', views.TestViewSet)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
)
```

What i would like to do is adding a new ViewSet which provides "subfunctionality" of test (urls.py):

```
router.register(r'test/add', views.TestNewViewSet)
```

But this does not work. When accessing this api, all i get is a "404 Not Found" error. No exceptions are thrown when accessing the api. So what is wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
url(r'^test/add/$',  TestNewViewSet.as_view(), name='whatever'),
```

)

Comment: Thanks! True, it is not possible to add a path with slashes when using a router. Everything after a slash is a "lookup" value and not part of the prefix: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#defaultrouter